# unable to plot graph using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have been trying to find the shortest distance two points on a grid. I am having 2 issue:

1) I am unable to come up with an efficient algorithm to find the path between the points.

2) there are 4 different points I am working with. 0 is the starting point, 1 means an obstacle, 2 s the ending point and 3 shows the points that are visited. I want the point that have been visited to turn red. but when I do so more than half of the graph turns red.

here's my code:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib import pyplot
import numpy as np


grid = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,2,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0],
    ]





def search(x, y):
    if grid[x][y] == 2:
        print ('found at %d,%d' % (x, y))
        return True
    elif grid[x][y] == 1:
        #print ('wall at %d,%d' % (x, y))
        return False
    elif grid[x][y] == 3:
        print ('visited at %d,%d' % (x, y))
        return False

    #print ('visiting %d,%d' % (x, y))

    # mark as visited
    grid[x][y] = 3

    # explore neighbors clockwise starting by the one on the right
    if ((x < len(grid)-1 and search(x+1, y))
        or (y > 0 and search(x, y-1))
        or (x > 0 and search(x-1, y))
        or (y < len(grid)-1 and search(x, y+1))):
        return True

    return False

search(0, 0)

zvals = grid

ax = pyplot.gca()
major_ticks = np.arange(0.5, 20, 1)
pyplot.xticks(rotation=90)
ax.set_xticks(major_ticks)
ax.set_yticks(major_ticks)
ax.grid(which='both')
pyplot.grid(True)

# make a color map of fixed colors
cmap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(['white','black'])
bounds=[-2,-1,1,2]
norm = mpl.colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)

# tell imshow about color map so that only set colors are used
img = pyplot.imshow(zvals,interpolation='nearest',
                    cmap = cmap,norm=norm)

# make a color bar
pyplot.colorbar(img,cmap=cmap,
                norm=norm,boundaries=bounds,ticks=[0,1])

pyplot.show()
```

Comment: Could you restrict your question to *one* question only?

Comment: Aah got it. Recursive function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the algorithm itself works fine I supose the only problem is to show the result correclty. I would suggest to use as many different colors as possible states on the grid, here 4 different ones.

```
# make a color map of fixed colors
cmap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(['white','black','red','limegreen'])
bounds=[-.5,0.5,1.5,2.5,3.5]
norm = mpl.colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)

# tell imshow about color map so that only set colors are used
img = pyplot.imshow(zvals,interpolation='nearest', norm=norm, cmap=cmap)

# make a color bar
pyplot.colorbar(img, ticks=list(range(4)))
```

[image]